# How can i compare two strings in a template of django?

Tags: html, css, django

I am new to Django and i am trying to make a blog website where user first login to create their post. They can update their existing post later. but the problem is other logged in user can also interfere with the post of this user.

so i was trying this logic,
{% if post.author == user.username %} in my post_detail.html file.
i.e. if person who has just logged (user.username) in is the same person who has written this post (post.author) then he is allowed  to edit or remove this post.
if not then option of edit & remove won't be visible to them on browser.

**I think i should try matching id of user( who has logged in) and author (who has written the post) because two users can have same name ( but not id )so both can interfere with each other post. Could you please help me with that.**

below are my models.py and other files.

```py
#models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404,  redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse

from django.urls import reverse

from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.

class user_entry(models.Model):
    # models.Model means that the Post is a Django Model, so Django knows that it should be saved in the database.

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    # email = models.EmailField(max_length=254,unique=True)
    # password=models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank = False, null= False)
    # models.ForeignKey – this is a link to another model here USER model as we want only login persons can post.
    # on_delete = models.CASCADE – This is the default value.
    # It automatically deletes all the related records when a record is deleted.(e.g. when an Album record is deleted all
    # the Song records related to it will be deleted)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null= True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("blog:post_detail", kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def approve_comments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approved_comment=True)
        # from total comments on post , only approved comments will be filtered and returned (shown on blog ), unapproved comments will be rejected.


    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        # self - connects method and its arguments to instance of a class.
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    # when we call __str__() we will get a text (string) with a Post title.

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments',null= True)
    # The related_name option in models.ForeignKey allows us to have access to comments from within the Post model.
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=False)
    text = models.TextField(blank=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text



     #  HOW TO SAVE OUR MODEL IN DATABASE?
     # First we have to make Django know that we have some changes in our model.
     #  (We have just created it!) Go to your console window and type python manage.py makemigrations blog
     #
     #  Django prepared a migration file for us that we now have to apply to our database. Type python manage.py migrate blog.
     #
     #  Our Post model is now in our database! It would be nice to see it, right? Jump to the next chapter to see what your Post looks like!

     # To add, edit and delete the posts we've just modeled, we will use Django admin.
     # To make our model visible on the admin page, we need to register the model with admin.site.register(Post).
```

```html
#post_detail.html

{%  extends 'blog/icon_base.html'  %}

{% block body_block %}
    <br>

    <div class="container">

        {% if user.is_authenticated %}


                    {% if post.author == user.username %}
                            <p>

                              <table
                              <tr>
                                <td><p><a class="btn btn-warning" href="{% url 'blog:post_edit' pk=post.pk %}">Update</a></p></td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td><p><a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'blog:post_remove' pk=post.pk %}">Delete</a></p></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>

                            </p>
                    {% endif %}









              {% if post.published_date %}
                  <time class="date">
                      {{ post.published_date }}
                  </time>
              {% endif %}
              <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>

              <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
              <hr>
              <p><a class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'blog:add_comment_to_post' pk=post.pk %}">Add Comment</a></p>
              <hr>
              {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
                    {% if comment.approved_comment or user.is_authenticated %}

                          {% if not comment.approved_comment %}
                          <p>
                            <table>
                            <tr>
                              <td>  <p><a  href="{% url 'blog:comment_approve' pk=comment.pk %}">✅</a></p></td>
                              <td>&nbsp;</td>
                              <td>&nbsp;</td>
                              <td><p><a href="{% url 'blog:comment_remove' pk=comment.pk %}">❌</a></p></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                          </p>
                          {% endif %}
                        <div class="date">{{ comment.created_date }}</div>
                        <strong>{{ comment.author }} said,</strong>
                        <p>{{ comment.text|linebreaks }}</p>

                        <hr>


                    {% endif %}
                    {% empty %}
                    <p>No comments here yet :(</p>

              {% endfor %}


        {% else %}


             {% if post.published_date %}
                 <time class="date">
                     {{ post.published_date }}
                 </time>
             {% endif %}
             <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
             <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
             <hr>
             <br>
             <h6>Note: Please Register and Log in to Create New Post and Comment on Posts</h6>
             <hr>
             <h4>Comments:</h4>
             <hr>
             {% for comment in post.comments.all %}

                 <div class="comment">
                     <div class="date">{{ comment.created_date }}</div>
                     <strong>{{ comment.author }} said,</strong>
                     <p>{{ comment.text|linebreaks }}</p>
                 </div>
                 <hr>
             {% empty %}
                 <p>No comments here yet :(</p>
             {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}


    </div>




{% endblock %}
```

```py
#views.py

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse

from django.urls import reverse
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from django.views.generic import TemplateView,ListView,DetailView,CreateView,UpdateView,DeleteView
from blog import models

from blog.models import user_entry
from blog.forms import user_entry_form

from blog.models import Post
from blog.forms import PostForm

from blog.models import Comment
from blog.forms import CommentForm

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from django.utils import timezone



# Create your views here.

# CLASS BASED VIEWS

# HOME
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

# check
class AboutView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'about.html'


# FUNCTION TO REGISTER

def register(request):

    registered = False

    # we will depend on this variable to tell if someone is registered or not!

    if request.method == "POST":
        UserEntryForm = user_entry_form(data=request.POST)

        # Check to see both forms are valid
        if UserEntryForm.is_valid():

            # Save User Form to Database
            user = UserEntryForm.save()
            # Hash the password
            user.set_password(user.password)

            # Update Database with Hashed password

            user.save()
            registered = True

        else:
            print(UserEntryForm.errors)

    else:
        UserEntryForm = user_entry_form()


    return render(request,'blog/register.html',
                                        {'UserEntryForm':UserEntryForm,
                                          'registered':registered})

# FUNCTION TO LOG IN

def user_login(request):
    # log_in = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # First get the username and password supplied
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)

        # If we have a user
        if user:
            #Check if the account is active
            if user.is_active:

                # Log the user in.
                login(request,user)
                # Send the user back to some page.
                # In this case their homepage.
                # log_in = True

                return render(request,'blog/home.html')
                # return HttpResponseRedirect(request,reverse('home'),{'log_in':log_in})

            else:
                # If account is not active:
                return HttpResponse("ACCOUNT NOT ACTIVE")
        else:
            print("Someone tried to login and failed.")
            print("Username: {} and password: {} ".format(username,password))
            return HttpResponse("invalid login details supplied.")

    else:
        #Nothing has been provided for username or password.
        return render(request, 'blog/login.html', {})

# FUNCTION TO LOG OUT

@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))

# POST LIST
class PostListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')
    # model= Post
    model = models.Post
    # def get_queryset(self):
    #     return Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')
    template_name = 'post_list.html'

# POST DETAIL
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'post'
    model = models.Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'


# POST CREATE
class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    fields = ('title', 'text')
    # These are fields that we will allow user to create.
    # it almost  acts like a security measure, may be we don'want someone to edit the location of school or the name of school etc.
    model = models.Post


# POST UPDATE
class PostUpdateView(UpdateView):
    fields = ('title', 'text')
    model = models.Post

# POST DELETE
class PostDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = models.Post
    success_url = reverse_lazy('blog:post_list')

 # COMMENT CREATE
def add_comment_to_post(request,pk):
    # In order to add comment to a post, we take in a request & the primary key that links the actual comment to the post.
    #  So, if u are on post detail page and you click OK, i want to comment on this , there is a primary key that goes along with that post.
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk)
        # either get that post object or 404 page (means u can't find it ) and pass in the Post model and then pk=pk.
    #   IF SOMEONE COMMENTS
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)

            comment.post = post
            #  connecting that particular comment to the Post's object.(see models for clarification , where post is field of Comment Model)
            comment.save()
            return redirect('blog:post_detail', pk=post.pk)
            # after comment done , redirecting user to post_detail page and also making post's primary key equal to comment primary key.
        #   IF SOMEONE DOES NOT COMMENT
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
        return render(request,'blog/comment_form.html',{'form':form})

# COMMENT APPROVE
def comment_approve(request,pk):
    comment=get_object_or_404(Comment,pk=pk)
    comment.approve()
    return redirect('blog:post_detail', pk=comment.post.pk)
# pk=comment.post.pk ?
    # remember the comment is connected to a particular post (in Comment Model),& if we want to approve that comment , go to the post of that comment ,
    # ...then i need the post.pk
    # ...now we actually go to Post Model ,and we will ask what's the primary key of the post that this comment was linked to
    # ...(as post of Comment Model is a foreign key, so we can grab primary key from Post Model )

# COMMENT DELETE
def comment_remove(request,pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment,pk=pk)
    post_pk = comment.post.pk
    comment.delete()
    return redirect('blog:post_detail',pk=post_pk)
```

```py
blog/urls.py

from blog import views
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path


app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^login/$', views.user_login,name='login'),
    url(r'^about/$', views.AboutView.as_view(),name='about'),

    url(r'^register/$', views.register,name='register'),

    url(r'^logout/$', views.user_logout,name='logout'),

    url(r'^post_list/$', views.PostListView.as_view(),name='post_list'),


    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/comment/$', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment_to_post'),
    url(r'^comment/(?P<pk>\d+)/approve/$', views.comment_approve, name='comment_approve'),
    url(r'^comment/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$', views.comment_remove, name='comment_remove'),

    # This means if you enter http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/5/ into your browser,
    # Django will understand that you are looking for a view called post_detail and transfer the information that pk equals 5 to that view.
    path('post/new/', views.PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post_new'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/edit/', views.PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_edit'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/remove/', views.PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post_remove'),

]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the way that you have tried:`{% if post.author == user.username %}`
but the problem is `post.author` is a user object, so user the following code.
in your code. if `user.username` is logged in user replace it with `request.user`

```
{% if post.author == request.user %}
```

Comment: It's not working bro ! I really appreciate u tried to help. I think i should try matching id of user( who has logged in)  and author (who has written the post) because two users can have same name so both can interfere with each other post. Could you please help me with  that.

Comment: try to print both `<p>{{post.author}}</p>` and `<p>{{request.user}}`</p> in your template. then let me see what it shows.

Comment: I tried this , there is no output for post.author  ,           <p>Author: {{post.author}}</p>
          <p>User: {{request.user}}</p>  ,  O/p on browser: Author:      

User:Jose

Comment: you are using this in post details page right?.  did you get the details of that post without using `{% if post.author == request.user %}` this if else.

Comment: If you are not getting the output for `post.author` then there is the problem. try to print `{{ post }}` . or what is the object that you are passing when calling the details of the specific post.

Comment: I am using all this in post_detail.html page. I am getting output for {{ post.published_date }} but not for {{ post.author}}. though both are fields of Post model. I don't know why it's happening? Actually i want to get id of author so that i can compare it with id of user , this will be good idea so that we can avoid problem of two users having same name.

Comment: Can you plz help me to get id of author which is a field in Post model?

Comment: Actually, you don't have to get the Id to compare. the code I gave in answer will work. you can compare between two objects. So try to get `post.author` or `post.user` . do you get any output for `{{post.title}} {{post.text}} {{post.author}} {{post.user}}`

Comment: FINALLY PROBLEM SOLVED ! i just used this comparision with ids.   {% if post.author_id == user.id %} if this is true, then we will allow user to edit or delete the post. You can watch you tube link also for that below!       https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1Us5jVT07E&list=PLCC34OHNcOtr025c1kHSPrnP18YPB-NFi&index=16

Answer (score 0):

See you are comparing `post.author`(which is a user object) with `user.username` (which is a field of user object) so this comparison would not return true. You can't compare between a string and a object.

Either you use

```
post.author.username ==  user.username
```

Or you can use template tag for more tricky operation in templates.
Hope it would help :)

Comment: It's not working bro ! I really appreciate u tried to help. I think i should try matching id of user( who has logged in)  and author (who has written the post) because two users can have same name so both can interfere with each other post. Could you please help me with  that.

Comment: FINALLY PROBLEM SOLVED ! i just used this comparision with ids.   {% if post.author_id == user.id %} if this is true, then we will allow user to edit or delete the post. You can watch you tube link also for that below!       https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1Us5jVT07E&list=PLCC34OHNcOtr025c1kHSPrnP18YPB-NFi&index=16